VSCode Dev Containers does not show "Attach Visual Studio Code" in right-click menu for a pod
I'm trying to follow the suggestions from the "Attach to a running container" article by Visual Studio Code and the image there shows an "Attach Visual Studio Code" in the right click menu for a pod.
I am connected to a linux system using Remote SSH on VS Code and I am connected to my kubernetes cluster using a kubeconfig file. When I go to the pod I want to attach VS Code to and right click, I do not have "Attach Visual Studio Code". See attached screenshot below.
Pod right-click menu from VS Code
Extension Versions:

Kubernetes @ v1.3.16
Dev Containers @ v0.375.1

After installing Kubernetes and Dev Containers VS Code extensions, I right-clicked on a pod and expected "Attach Visual Studio Code" to be available in the menu, but it wasn't.
